# AutoComplete no search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, autocomplete

I need to change the value of a hidden value, depending if the search of the autocomplete had any results. I know that the ui-autocomplete displays a span that is something like this:

```
<span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span>
```

I need to know the results of the search when I am using a onChange event in an input.

My code has to be something like this:

```
    function onChangeHiddenValue() {
    if(search == 'No results) --> I need to change this
        {
        document.forms['form'].elements['hiddenId'].value = cliente.id;
        }
    else
        {
        document.forms['form'].elements['hiddenId'].value = null;
        }
  }
```

My Html code is something like this

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="uppercase"><fmt:message key="user.name" /></label>
        <form:input  onchange="onChangeHiddenValue();" cssClass="form-control" path="user.name" id="name"disabled="${readonly}" submitbyenter="true" />
        <form:errors path="user.id" cssClass="error-block" />
        <form:hidden path="user.id" id="userId" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the response event to check if there are results and if there aren't, then you can set the value of the hidden input.

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your span will say "0 result..." when none are found this should work for you:

Add an ID to your span tag like id="searchid"

```
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("searchid").innerHTML.charAt(0)) > 0)
```

**EDIT:**
Since you can't add an id to the span and there is not always a number at the start of the string. Add the ID to the div tag then try using this:

```
var searchbox=document.getElementById('searchid');
var searchresult=searchbox.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
try {
    var number = parseInt(searchresult.charAt(0));
    if(number > 0)
    {
        document.forms['form'].elements['hiddenId'].value = null;
    }
    else
    {
        document.forms['form'].elements['hiddenId'].value = cliente.id;
    }
}
catch(err) {
    document.forms['form'].elements['hiddenId'].value = cliente.id;
}
```

Comment: I use the autocomplete widget from jquery, the span that it returns has no id or anything and the text is like "No results...etc". See my html code from the form

Comment: Where does is the span created in your HTML, is it inside the label tags?

Comment: The span is created by the jquery widget, it does all the work, and it creates the span before the input